# node.js EventEmitter and iife pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, eventemitter

I have a question specific a bit to inheritance in javascript rather than node.js:

```
// foo.js
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');

var Foo = (function(){
    var foo = {};
    events.EventEmitter.call(foo);
    foo.init = function(){
        foo.emit('bar');
    };

    util.inherits(parser, events.EventEmitter);

    return { 
        bind: foo.init,
        on: foo.on // I suppose this resolves to event emitter's on method
    };

}());

module.exports = Foo;
```

Then, when i simply try to call (say in main.js):

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');

foo.on('bar', function(){ ... });
```

An error is generated before i even call `foo.init();`:

```
foo.on('bar', function(){ ... })
       ^
TypeError: Property 'on' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Isn't it possible to inherit from EventEmitter when I chose to code in IIFE pattern? Or my error is related something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep this pattern, and you have a good reason for not using prototypal inheritance like this:

```
FooConstuctor.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();
```

Then, if all you need from the **EventEmitter** is the *on* method, you can just add:

```
Foo.on = events.EventEmitter.prototype.on;
```

Right after you create **Foo**.

You don't get the *on* method on **Foo** just by invoking **EventEmitter**'s constructor on **Foo** because the *on* method isn't attached to **EventEmitter** objects in the constructor.

The reason for that is probably that it's usually considered bad practice to assign methods to your objects in their constructor, because then, a new function **instance** is created for each object instance which is unnecessary usually and wasteful, and methods created like this aren't directly assigned to the prototype, which can be misleading for other developers planning to extend your "class".

Comment: Nice explanation, however, I want to keep my pattern in order to encapsulate and not to provide all of my functions right away.

Comment: Since this is written in **Node.js**, no local variable will 'leak' out to global scope anyway, so you shouldn't worry about that. Only what's assigned to the *exports* property is available outside of the module. Besisdes, the solution I suggested takes into account that you want to keep this pattern and doesn't conflict with it. (only the second line of code is relevant).

Answer (score 2):

If I need an object that acts like an EventEmitter with the module pattern I prefer the following:

```
var foo = function () {

  var ee = new EventEmitter();

  /* custom logic */

  return {
    on: ee.on.bind(ee),
    emit: ee.emit.bind(ee),
  }

};
```